# hidden field value set by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code  setting text filed value like:

```
$('#chargetotal').val('20.00');
```

text field is:

```
<input type="text" id="chargetotal" value=""/>
```

After inspect element of my browser ,It looks like

```
<input type="text" id="chargetotal" value>
```

But the text filed has  value `20.00`.

My question is that,why am I getting this:

```
<input type="text" id="chargetotal" value>
```

I should get:

```
 <input type="text" id="chargetotal" value="20.00">
```

Comment: Could you add a fiddle? It looks like this should work.

Comment: @mark which is not needed in HTML5

Comment: If you view the source prior to running the jQuery, it also shows `<input type="text" id="chargetotal" value>`. In fact, the browser shows all empty attributes like that (in Chrome at least).

Comment: Thanks for response . @Bala give answer of it. .attr('value','someValue')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `.val()` wont change anything in the source while you inspect it since it is storing the value internally inside of the corresponding element object, if you want to reflect the changes in the source then you should use `.attr('value','someValue')`.